# JQuery: adding items to list and keeping count of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of items(for this I have only included one), and I am trying to add more items to my list.  While I can insert a new item at the end of the list, I can not get the id number to be set, it always comes out as 0.

```
<script>
    var count = $("#playlist").children().length;

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("ul").append(
          $('<li>').attr('id', 'list['+ count +']').append(
            $('<div>').attr('class','item').append(
              $('<fieldset>').append(
                "<input id='list[i][name]' name='list[i][name]' type='text' class='auto' size='40' value ='NEW "+ count +"'>"
              )
            )
          )
        )
      })
    });
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div class='holder'>
   <ul id="playlist">
        <li id='list[1]' ><div class='item'><fieldset>
            <input id='list[1][name]' name='list[1][name]' type='text' class='auto' size='40' value ='one' />
        </fieldset></div></li>
   </ul>
   <br>
<button>Add new list item</button>
</div>
```

Comment: how about `count++`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `count` variable inside the event listener, so it actually increases when clicking

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        var count = $("#playlist").children().length;
        $("ul").append(
            $('<li>').attr('id', 'list[' + count + ']').append(
                $('<div>').attr('class', 'item').append(
                    $('<fieldset>').append(
                        "<input id='list[i][name]' name='list[i][name]' type='text' class='auto' size='40' value ='NEW " + count + "'>"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    })
});
```

Right now you're getting the `count` before the document loads, when `#playlist` isn't even accessible, so the count is always `0`.

Comment: Thanks I knew I was close.

Answer (score 0):

You have t calculate the count on every click
or may be increment it by one, if you don't plan in removing them

see the below example
https://jsfiddle.net/ammar08429/1bLh6dqk/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  var count = $("#playlist").children().length;
    $("ul").append(
      $('<li>').attr('id', 'list['+ count +']').append(
        $('<div>').attr('class','item').append(
          $('<fieldset>').append(
            "<input id='list[i][name]' name='list[i][name]' type='text' class='auto' size='40' value ='NEW "+ count +"'>"
))))})});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can add `count++` before appending

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v9pvusgq/)

```js
var count = $("#playlist").children().length;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    
    count++; ////////////////add this line

    $("ul").append(
      $('<li>').attr('id', 'list[' + count + ']').append(
        $('<div>').attr('class', 'item').append(
          $('<fieldset>').append(
            "<input id='list[i][name]' name='list[i][name]' type='text' class='auto' size='40' value ='NEW " + count + "'>"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='holder'>
  <ul id="playlist">
    <li id='list[1]'>
      <div class='item'>
        <fieldset>
          <input id='list[1][name]' name='list[1][name]' type='text' class='auto' size='40' value='one' />
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <button>Add new list item</button>
</div>
```